# Maven fails due to connection reset while trying to download a dependency which is already downloaded

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, github-actions

I am encountering an very strange issue on GitHub Actions while trying to run a maven command for integration tests.

To give the full context, i am migrating from Jenkins to GitHub actions an insanely huge project consisting of thousands of lines of code and ~200 modules. I have almost completed this, but I missing the integration tests job. All of our GitHub Actions runners are ephemeral so each job is a whole new machine, so I must install maven java etc every single time which I do.

The maven commands used to run the integration tests are the following:

```
run-integration-tests: 
    mvn clean verify \
        --update-snapshots \
        --quiet \
        -E \
        -DskipUTs -DskipE2ETests \
        -Dexec.skip=true  \
        -Ddocker.logs.show=false \
        -PJENKINS \
        -fae
```

(there is a wrapper using a makefile for simplicitity but essentially it runs maven verify)

Now the problem: since the project has a lot of modules, it take ~1h to complete all these integration tests. After about ~43 minutes, every single time it fails with this error:

```
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6033494Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project voxbone-fulfillment-e2e-tests: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.voxbone:voxbone-fulfillment-e2e-tests:jar:121.1.1-trunk-85: Failed to collect dependencies at com.voxbone.voxrating:platform-api-tool:jar:4.5.7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.voxbone.voxrating:platform-api-tool:jar:4.5.7: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.voxbone.voxrating:platform-api-tool:pom:4.5.7 (absent): Could not transfer artifact com.voxbone.voxrating:platform-api-tool:pom:4.5.7 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6036936Z [ERROR] 
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6037446Z [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6038000Z [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6038345Z [ERROR] 
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6038733Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6039437Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6039845Z [ERROR] 
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6040225Z [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6040950Z [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :voxbone-fulfillment-e2e-tests
2023-07-12T10:57:08.6993271Z make: *** [makefile:45: run-integration-tests] Error 1
2023-07-12T10:57:08.7004001Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.
```

What I find extremely confusing is that this dependency with this exact version has already been downloaded and is present in the .m2 folder before running the integration tests so i I cannot find a reason why maven would decide to download it again. Also its worth mentioning that it is not a compilation error since mvn clean install works every time I run it.

Keep in mind that that this dependency is present on a private repository (JFrog) and it is configured in pom.xml.

What's even stranger is that this does not happen on Jenkins running the exact same command with the exact same java maven config etc.

I am out of ideas what to check/debug so any hint would be very appreciated.

I've been trying multiple solutions for days now:

- messing with maven wagon arguments
- i used a ssh connection to check if the dependency is present in .m2
- i tried running mvn dependency:resolve before integration tests and still the same output
- also mvn dependency:go-offline and running IT command in offline mode but it fails because it can't download some dependency ):